# FlutterでGoogle画像検索のサムネイルが拡大された画面を表示したい

Tags: ios, android, html, flutter

ー前提ー
Flutterでiosとandroidのスマホアプリを開発中です。
Flutterやhtml、StackOverflow初心者なので不備等ございましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

ーやりたいことー
下の画像のようにGoogle画像検索で1枚目のサムネイルが拡大された画面を表示したいです。

※画像はPCのものになります。
[image: 「祭り」と検索し、1枚目の画像をクリックしたときの例]

ーできていることー
下記画像のような画像検索の一覧画面は表示することができています。
また、画像検索のURLの後ろに「[URL]#imgrc=〜〜」の形で追記するとサムネイルが拡大されることはわかっています。
※先ほどの「祭り」の例であれば「[URL]#imgrc=WjCM7x6auEFxBM」

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ーできないことー
「#imgrc=〜〜」の〜〜の値の取得方法がわからず困っております。
この値さえFlutterで取得できればやりたいことが実装可能なのですが、、、

どなたかお知恵をお貸しいただけると幸いです。